# Why does Google use invalid HTML attributes? And does this mean I can too?

Tags: html, markup, custom-data-attribute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is xhtml's role attribute? What do you use it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678238/what-is-xhtmls-role-attribute-what-do-you-use-it-for)

I noticed one element in Gmail had an attribute named "role", i.e. `<div role="whatever">`. Technically that's invalid. But I also know that most browsers will understand it without any trouble, as will jQuery (and perhaps straight JS?). Personally, I like this more than prefixing all custom attributes with "data-".

Any idea why Google does this? And can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

role="" is an ARIA attribute used for screen readers and as an accessibility aid. Read http://www.accessibleculture.org/articles/2011/04/html5-aria-2011/ for more info. I recommend people start using them on their websites in order to aid those who view our sites in different ways the same level of access as a "normal" user.

Answer (score 0):

The role attribute actually validates in HTML5. In prior versions of HTML (and XHTML) it doesn't validate, but it's supported by screen readers and ignored by browsers regardless of your doctype. Therefore accessibility advocates encourage people to use it, despite failed validation, as it provides additional semantics that can help assistive technology users. The philosophy is essentially to follow the rules (validate) but also know when it's ok to break the rules (e.g., if doing so helps some users without harming others). An even better solution though is to upgrade to HTML5 - that way you can use ARIA markup **and** validate.